# stochastic integrals w.r.t. stable processes: integration by parts

Tags: stochastic-processes

For the stochastic integrals w.r.t. stable processes of a determinated (non-random) function, does there exist a corresponding integration by parts formula?

[image]

Thank you very much!

Ps. It is my first time to post a question on the web. Very Sorry!

Comment: Define your terms: which "stochastic integrals", "determined function"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These [notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-070j-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT15_070JF13_Lec17.pdf) from an MIT course discuss Itô processes.  Here's the integration by parts formula they give:

$$ \int_0^t f_s \, dB_s = f_t B_t - \int_0^t B_s \, df_s $$

where $f_s$ is a (deterministic) continuous function on $[0,t]$.  The notes are from the business school and so the details are skipped.

---

As long as $f(s)$ is deterministic we have some back-of the envelope computations:

\begin{eqnarray} \Delta \big(f(s) B_s\big) &=& f(s + \Delta s)B_{s + \Delta s}
- f(s )B_{s} \\ \\
&=& \big[f(s + \Delta s) - f(s)\big]B_{s + \Delta s} - f(s) \big[ B_{s+\Delta s} - B_s\big] \\ \\ 
&=& \Delta f(s)\, B_{s + \Delta s} -   f(s) \,\Delta B_s\end{eqnarray}

Itô's formula is not goint to tell us anything new.  It tells us very familiar things such as:
$$ \int_o^t s \, dB_t = t\, B_t - \int_0^t B_s \, ds$$
More in [Øksendal](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540047582)'s book.